# Need an open source crawler like Apache Nutch without Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I need an open source crawler with features like url normalizer, url filter, parser, politeness, excluding some urls but what i'm doing is not big in anyway. It is just about 500 hosts with their 1 level outlinks that i need to keep up to date. I don't like to reinvent the wheel by implementing all these good features that Nutch has meanwhile i don't like the overhead of Hadoop for this small task.

Is there any fork of Nutch without Hadoop? or any other simple crawler with these features?
I don't need any adaptive fetch scheduling, ranking, etc. I just have a list of hosts that i should fetch their outlinks using one single machine.

My preference is some fork of Nutch because i have experience using it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need the linux command `wget`.
For example, assume that the hosts are put in the file `hosts.txt`. You can use the following command to download them:

```
for host in `cat hosts.txt` ; do wget -r -d 1 -H "$host"; done
```

-r means recursive, -d 1 means only download the level 1, -H means do not limit the domain name.

You can search `wget recursive download` in google, or run `man wget` to get more information.

Comment: Yes, but i need it to be multithreaded and in the same time i need to follow politeness rules (don't send many simultaneous requests to one server). I also need a parser to extract outlinks, a url normalization to normalize urls, a url filtering tool to exclude some urls. There is some other required features such as detecting mimetype, storing them in lucene, etc. I can implement all these but they are already implemented in some crawlers like Nutch. The problem with Nutch is that it is highly coupled with Hadoop which i don't need.

Comment: Then I think Heritrix is an alternative: https://github.com/internetarchive/heritrix3

Answer (score 0):

Nutch is no longer bound to Hadoop:

> By default, Nutch no longer comes with a Hadoop distribution, however
>   when run in local mode e.g. running Nutch in a single process on one
>   machine, then we use Hadoop as a dependency. This may suit you fine if
>   you have a small site to crawl and index, but most people choose Nutch
>   because of its capability to run on in deploy mode, within a Hadoop
>   cluster.

from: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial